# How to dynamically inject buttons into Angular 6 app?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm building a web application with a component that displays Material UI buttons based on data is receives from an API.

**Workflow:**

The workflow of the component I'm trying to build works like this:

(1) the page loads, makes an API call to receive 30 random words from the backend, and the first three words are displayed in the form of buttons to the user

(2) The user clicks on one word. The other two are then automatically disabled. The following three words are selected and displayed / injected as new buttons on the page.

(3) When all 30 words have been displayed to the user, the next click retrieves 30 more, and the process continues indefinitely.

What is the best way to dynamically generate those buttons, and insert them into the UI?

Below are snippets of my code thus far. Although, if anyone has a better approach, I'll gladly use it! :)

**Data Sample:**

```
["word1", "word2", "word3", …, "word30"]
```

**Template:**

```
 this.templateButtonRow$ = `
      <div class="button-row">
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="registerWord(WORD)">
          WORD
        </button>
      </div>`;
```

**Injection code:**

```
@ViewChild('buttonrows', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;
…
const tmpCmp = Component({template: this.templateButtonRow$})(class {});
  const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpCmp], entryComponents: [tmpCmp]})(class {});
  this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
    .then((factories) => {
      const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
      const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
      cmpRef.instance.name = 'B component';
      this.vc.insert(cmpRef.hostView)
    });
```

**Problems:**

- The code above injects the raw HTML. It's not compiled to apply Material UI.
- Also, when we click on the button, it's context is invalid, and the registerWord() function cannot be called.

** Screenshot:**

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Sincerely,
Alex

Comment: Can you add an example of the JSON data you get from the API? Thanks

Comment: Use ngIf / ngFor in the template of the component, to display the buttons based on the model. Do NOT generate/compile html in your component. That's the role of the template.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why you are creating a temporary component and a temporary module just to show a button. In years of Angular programming I've never seen anything like this, where did you get inspired to do it?

Comment: Hi Everybody! Thank you for attempting to help! I have updated the content of this question to provide the clarifications you requested. Once again, thank you for trying to help me out, and I look forward to reading your suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Comment: @CristianTraìna, I got the idea from here: https://github.com/maximusk/Here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-Angular/issues/1

Comment: Is there a reason why you use dynamic components in place of ngFor and ngIf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad approach to dynamically show and hide an element in Angular, you should avoid it if you don't have a strong reason to do it.

By the way, you are declaring your component in a temporary module, but this module hasn't imported `MatButtonModule`, so Angular can't resolve the directives.

Import `MatButtonModule` in your temporary module:

```
const tmpModule = NgModule({
  imports: [MatButtonModule], 
  declarations: [tmpCmp], 
  entryComponents: [tmpCmp]})
  (class {});
```